# Finding relations of variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, contest-math

Suppose that

\begin{align*}
x&=t+t^{-1}+t^2s+t^{-2}s^{-1}+ts^{-1}+t^{-1}s-6\\
y&=t+t^{-2}+ts+s^{-1}-4\\
z&=t^{-1}+t^2+t^{-1}s^{-1}+s-4
\end{align*}

Find a polynomial $P(x, y, z)=0$ relating $x$, $y$ and $z$.

In general, if we are given
\begin{align*}
x_1&=P_1(t_1, \cdots, t_m)\\
\vdots&\\
x_n&=P_n(t_1, \cdots, t_m)
\end{align*} 
where $P_1, \cdots, P_n$ are polynomials, is there a general way we can find polynomial relations of $x_1, \cdots, x_n$? I know that when $n=2$ and $m=1$, a polynomial relation is given by the resultant of $P_1(t_1)-x_1$ and $P_2(t_1)-x_2$.

Comment: Well, you could try to homogenise the expressions for $x,y,$ and $z$ and compute their multivariate resultant...

Comment: Could you please point out a reference on multivariate resultant? I don't know what that is. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the book by Cox, Little, and O' Shea titled [Using Algebraic Geometry](https://books.google.it/books?id=QFFpepgQgT0C&lpg=PP1&dq=isbn%3A9780387207339&pg=PA84#v=onepage&q&f=false), chapter 3. (note: I just found out about this with a quick search, so I'm no expert, but it does sound like what you are looking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, Cox, Little, and O'Shea have written about how to solve the implicitization problem, but in their first book *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms*. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1318832) for a reference to the result used below. (I think we could alternatively use multivariable resultants rather than Gröbner bases.)

Let $u = s^{-1}$ and $v = t^{-1}$. We form the ideal
\begin{align*}
I = (su - 1, tv - 1, x &- (t + v + t^2 s + v^2 u + t u + v s - 6),\\
y &- (t + v^2 + t s + u - 4), z - (v + t^2 + v u + s - 4))
\end{align*}
in $\mathbb{Q}[s,t,u,v,x,y,z])$, and compute a Gröbner basis $G$ with respect to the lexicographical order. The last entry of $G$ is a Gröbner basis for the elimination ideal $I \cap \mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$, and is the polynomial $P(x,y,z)$ you're looking for. Computing using [*SageMath*](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9jLEKgzAQhvdC3yE4RXsKxtIutau4VVfRohglYLUkKtqn752VDpfc_Xzfn3o3AyNMMMMCK3zuLGSPoVv74aXKLlV9y5MErjDoWurQ6uRi2cdD4yO2MJfxkZ3YjDMWwjG04z_Rvb0zZi67kCHQWP9GITaGjAnDMxEBEh8i9r7NpxazEzECqpZlxzPjkOYDdsy_paEROEGOaIRo7LV6kFUv9bMqjTIc87dW_cijzPVz-wtlj0Bx&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), we find
\begin{align*}
P(x,y,z) = x^{5} + 2 x^{4} y + 2 x^{4} z + 50 x^{4} - x^{3} y^{2} z - 7 x^{3} y^{2} - x^{3} y z^{2} - 17 x^{3} y z - 25 x^{3} y - 7 x^{3} z^{2} - 25 x^{3} z + 625 x^{3} + x^{2} y^{4} - 2 x^{2} y^{3} z + x^{2} y^{3} - 49 x^{2} y^{2} z - 245 x^{2} y^{2} - 2 x^{2} y z^{3} - 49 x^{2} y z^{2} - 610 x^{2} y z - 1875 x^{2} y + x^{2} z^{4} + x^{2} z^{3} - 245 x^{2} z^{2} - 1875 x^{2} z + 2 x y^{5} - x y^{4} z + 48 x y^{4} + x y^{3} z^{3} + 19 x y^{3} z^{2} + 66 x y^{3} z + 455 x y^{3} + 19 x y^{2} z^{3} + 336 x y^{2} z^{2} + 1245 x y^{2} z + 1875 x y^{2} - x y z^{4} + 66 x y z^{3} + 1245 x y z^{2} + 3750 x y z + 2 x z^{5} + 48 x z^{4} + 455 x z^{3} + 1875 x z^{2} + y^{6} - y^{5} z^{2} - 10 y^{5} z + 14 y^{5} - 23 y^{4} z^{2} - 237 y^{4} z - 19 y^{4} + 8 y^{3} z^{3} - 73 y^{3} z^{2} - 1564 y^{3} z - 625 y^{3} - y^{2} z^{5} - 23 y^{2} z^{4} - 73 y^{2} z^{3} + 366 y^{2} z^{2} - 1875 y^{2} z - 10 y z^{5} - 237 y z^{4} - 1564 y z^{3} - 1875 y z^{2} + z^{6} + 14 z^{5} - 19 z^{4} - 625 z^{3} \, .
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks so much for answering this question which has laid idle for many years! Just one more question: does the Gröbner basis algorithm or multivariate resultant give the polynomial relation of minimal degree? Sorry if this is answered in Cox-Little-O'Shea, but I do not have their book.

Comment: For Gröbner bases, the answer is yes. The polynomial $P$ you get from this method is a generator for the elimination ideal, so any other polynomial relation must be a multiple of $P$. I don't think this is necessarily true for resultants. The resultant will be an element of the elimination ideal, but might not generate the whole ideal.

Answer (score -1):

If the Jacobian

$\frac{d(x_1, \cdots, x_n)}{d(t_1, \cdots, t_m) }$

is non-zero there is no relationship like:

$ P(x, y, z)=0 $.

In fact, the system

\begin{align*}
x_1&=P_1(t_1, \cdots, t_m)\\
\vdots&\\
x_n&=P_n(t_1, \cdots, t_m)
\end{align*}

is invertible;

we can consider the $t_1, \cdots, t_m $ as dependent variables and the $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ as independent.

We can give $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ any values and this shows that there is no relation like:

$ P(x, y, z)=0 $.